# Angular modify directive from template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that displays buttons. **Quick example:**

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

Inside the directive is HTML similar to the following. (this will display two buttons once the page is rendered).

```
<button ng-repeat="option in options">{{option}}</button>
```

Here is a more detailed look at the directive I mentioned before:

```
<my-directive ng-model="someModel" options="[0, 1]" ui-options="['Cat', 'Dog']>
</my-directive>
```

**>>> Result:** 2 html buttons.

- Cat
- Dog

**Main Question**: I would like to disable the `Dog` button if a certain condition is met.

I've tried conditionally adding a `disabled` directive *to the directive* if the condition is met, but that disables BOTH the `Cat` and `Dog` buttons, like so: *(on the directive element)*

```
ng-attr-disabled="dogIsbad()"
```

of course, that disables both buttons because the attribute is on the directive. How can I only add the disabled attribute to the `Dog` button without modifying the actual directive?

Answer (score 1):

you could pass the option as a paramater to dogIsbad() and check if the option is dog.

```
<button ng-repeat="option in options" ng-disabled="dogIsbad(option)">{{option}}</button>
```

In controller

```
dogIsbad = function(option){ return (option == "Dog");}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to access the element from outside the directive, and without modifying it directly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass it in the options like

```
<my-directive 
  ng-model="someModel"  
  options="[0, 1]" 
  ui-options="[{'name': 'Cat', disabled: true}, {name: 'Dog', disabled: false}]>
</my-directive>
```

And then use it in the button display

```
<button ng-repeat="option in options" ng-disabled="option.disabled">{{option.name}}</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.options = ['cat', 'dog'];
    $scope.dogIsbad = function(option){      
      return option == 'dog';
    }
  }])
  .directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        options: '=',
        dogIsbad: '&'
      },
      template: '<button ng-disabled="dogIsbad({option: option})" ng-repeat="option in options">{{option}}</button>'
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl">
  <my-directive options="options" dog-isbad='dogIsbad(option)'></my-directive>
</div>
```